# Выделение памяти под двумерный массив malloc

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, malloc

Кто может показать пример **функции**, которая **выделит память под двумерный массив и вернет его** если это вообще возможно. И какие **параметры** нужно передать в эту функцию что бы достичь желаемого результата. Массив в итоге будет заполнен отдельными словами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Казалось бы, что может быть прямолинейнее, чем выделение динамически памяти под двумерный массив, а потому должно существовать одно решение.

На самом деле можно по-разному реализовать данную задачу.

Самый простой способ - это когда число колонок в двумерном массиве является константным значением, определенным либо с помощью директивы `#define` либо с помощью перечислителя. Тогда можно сразу же разместить динамически именно двумерный массив.

Второй подход, это когда число колонок задается во время выполнения программы. В этом случае обычно выделяют несколько одномерных массивов. Сначала выделяют одномерный массив указателей с количеством элементов равных количеству строк в предполагаемом двумерном массиве, А затем для каждого указателя этого одномерного массива выделяют массив объектов базового типа, число элементов которого равно числу колонок в двумерном массиве. В этом варианте важно учитывать, что во время выделения массивов может возникнуть нехватка памяти, а потому желательно правильно удалить те массивы, которые были уже распределены, а иначе программа будет иметь неопределенное состояние.

Третий подход заключается в использовании массивов переменной длины при условии, что C компилятор их поддерживает. Тогда число колонок и строк может быть задано во время выполнения программы, и можно выделить сразу же двумерный массив, а не массив массивов, как было описано в предыдущем абзаце.

Также следует не забывать корректно освобождать выделенную динамически память под массивы, когда массивы уже не нужны.

Ниже приведена демонстрационная программа, в которой показаны перечисленные способы выделения памяти для работы с двумерными массивами или их аналогами.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define COLS    10

char ( * first_allocate( size_t rows ) )[COLS]
{
    char ( *s )[COLS] = malloc( rows * sizeof( char[COLS] ) );

    return s;
}

void first_free( char ( *s )[COLS] )
{
    free( s );
}


char ** second_allocate( size_t rows, size_t cols )
{
    char **s = malloc( rows * sizeof( char * ) );

    if ( s != NULL )
    {
        size_t i = 0;

        while ( i < rows && ( s[i] = malloc( cols * sizeof( char ) ) ) != NULL ) i++;

        if ( i != rows )
        {
            for ( size_t j = i; j != 0; j-- ) free( s[j-1] );
            free( s );
            s = NULL;
        }

    }

    return s;
}

void second_free( char **s, size_t rows )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++ ) free( s[i] );
    free( s );
}

void third_allocate( size_t rows, size_t cols, char ( **s )[rows][cols] )
{
    *s = malloc( sizeof( char[rows][cols] ) );
}

void third_free( size_t rows, size_t cols, char ( *s )[rows][cols] )
{
    free( s );
}



int main( void )
{
    size_t rows = 2;
    size_t cols = 10;

    char ( *s1 )[COLS] = first_allocate( rows );
    strcpy( s1[0], "first" );
    strcpy( s1[1], "second" );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++ ) printf( "%s ", s1[i] );
    printf( "\n" );

    first_free( s1 );

    printf( "\n" );

    char **s2 = second_allocate( rows, cols );
    strcpy( s2[0], "first" );
    strcpy( s2[1], "second" );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++ ) printf( "%s ", s2[i] );
    printf( "\n" );

    second_free( s2, rows );

    printf( "\n" );

    char ( *s3 )[rows][cols] = NULL;

    third_allocate( rows, cols, &s3 );
    strcpy( ( *s3 )[0], "first" );
    strcpy( ( *s3 )[1], "second" );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++ ) printf( "%s ", ( *s3 )[i] );
    printf( "\n" );

    third_free( rows, cols, s3 );
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль будет следующим

```
first second 

first second 

first second
```

Comment: Спасибо, именно то что нужно) Четко коротко и ясно)

Comment: @m0le Не за что. Спрашивайте еще.:)